# How to convert a CRLF into a \n string

Tags: java, python, shell, newline, backslash

I am looking for a way to convert CRLF into a \n.
Exemple :

What i have :

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

What i expect :

```
Line 1\nLine 2
```

I have a application that hates CRLF LF and end of line ?

Looking to do it in shell script or java application at worse.

Thank you

Comment: unfortinatly no

Comment: @chubby.skelton : Don't you have [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) installed on your system? What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved with a second slash before the n to escape the first one.

Your code with a print statement would look something like this:

```
System.out.println("Line 1\\nLine 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell could be much faster really depending on how big the file is.

If you just want to change to say a "|"

```
cat file.txt | tr '\n' '|'
```

Output:

```
Line1|Line2|
```

if you must convert to a string (rather than one char)

```
cat file.txt | tr '\n' '|'  | sed s/\|/##/g
```

Output:

```
Line1##Line2##
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";ORS="\\n"}1' file
```

Output:

```
Line 1\nLine 2\n$
```

Works with mawk and Busybox awk, too.